# How to rotate SVG images that is clicked only

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I tried rotating the SVG images I used for my navbar when clicked. I managed to do that but the problem is when I click one of the buttons all the images rotate at once and when I click elsewhere the images are not reset to their original position.

this is my HTML

```
<!-- === Dropdown Menu === -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navToggler">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn" type="button" id="navButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      Product <img class="arrow reset" src="/blogr/images/icon-arrow-light.svg">
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navButton1">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Overview</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Pricing</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Marketplace</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Features</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Integrations</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn" type="button" id="navButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      Company <img class="arrow reset" src="/blogr/images/icon-arrow-light.svg">
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navButton1">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Team</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Career</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn" type="button" id="navButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      Connect <img class="arrow reset" src="/blogr/images/icon-arrow-light.svg">
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navButton1">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Newsletter</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">LinkedIn</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END -->
```

CSS

```
.rotate {
   transform: rotate(180deg);
   transition: .3s;
}
.arrow.reset{
   transform: rotate(0deg);
   transition: .3s;
}
```

Javascript

```
$("button#navButton1.btn").on("click", function () {

      $(".arrow").toggleClass("rotate");
      $(".arrow").toggleClass("reset");

});
```

What I want to happen:

[image]

What is happening on click:

[image: when click]

What is happening when I click another place:

[image: clicked at other places]

Answer (score 0):

In the onclick function you are selecting all `.arrow` in the document. I guess that what you want is to target the arrow inside the clicked `.btn`.

You have to pass a second argument to jQuery to tell it to search only inside that node. Something like this should do it:

```js
$('button#navButton1.btn').on('click', function (event) {
    $('.arrow', event.target)
        .toggleClass('rotate')
        .toggleClass('reset');
});
```